# Doing complex ordering with a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with a Mysql Query that require some "complex" ordering.
I've 2 tables:

```
Training
+--------------+------------------+
| training_id  | training_name    |
+--------------+------------------+
|            1 | test1            |
|            2 | test2            |
|            3 | test3            |
+--------------+------------------+

Training_venue
+----------+--------------+------------+
| venue_id | training_id  | venue_date |
+----------+--------------+------------+
|        1 |            2 | 2009-06-01 |
|        2 |            2 | 2012-06-01 |
|        3 |            2 | 2011-06-01 |
|        4 |            1 | 2009-09-01 |
|        5 |            1 | 2011-09-01 |
|        6 |            1 | 2012-09-01 |
|        7 |            3 | 2009-01-01 |
+----------+--------------+------------+
```

And I'm expecting the following results:

```
+--------------+------------------+------------+--------------+
| training_id  | training_name    | venue_id   | venue_date   |
+--------------+------------------+------------+--------------+
|            2 | test2            |          2 | 2011-06-01   |
|            2 | test2            |          3 | 2012-06-01   |
|            1 | test1            |          6 | 2011-09-01   |
|            1 | test1            |          5 | 2012-09-01   |
+--------------+------------------+------------+--------------+
```

As you can see, the result requirement are:

- A training with no future venue is discarded.
- Expired venue are discarded
- The trainings are "grouped" together
- The trainings with the soonest venue is first, the training with the "latest soonest venue" is last
- Inside the training, the venues are ordered from the soonest to the latest.

What mysql query will return that result set ?

Edit:
Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM `training` AS t
LEFT JOIN `training_venue` AS v USING ( `training_id` )
WHERE `venue_date` >= NOW()
ORDER BY `training_id;
```

But if the order by training_id take care of keeping all the training "grouped" together, it doesnt permit to order the training from the training with the soonest venue to the training with the lastest venue.

I also edited the data table to illustrate that problematic. See how the results are ordered, it's not by training_id, but by soonest venue.

Edit:
Corrected the dates.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us what the query you've managed to come up with so far is so we can help you finish it as opposed to just expecting someone to do all the work for you.

Comment: @AlanBarber You're right, I just edited.. hope it will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.training_id, t1.training_name, t2.venue_id, t2.venue_date
FROM Training t1
INNER JOIN Training_venue t2 ON t1.training_id = t2.training_id
WHERE t2.venue_date >= NOW()
ORDER BY t1.training_id ASC, t2.venue_date ASC
```

I don't know what your last point is getting at: "Inside the training, the venues are ordered from the soonest to the latest." But the above query seems to match the rest of your needs.

EDIT: I now sort of understand better what you are after. And it is a tad complicated I think. I'll have another think about it.

EDIT: I think I have it!

```
SELECT t1.training_id, t1.training_name, t2.venue_id, t2.venue_date 
FROM Training t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT training_id, venue_date 
FROM training_venue 
WHERE venue_date >= NOW()
GROUP BY training_id
ORDER BY MIN(venue_date)) t3 ON t1.training_id = t3.training_id
INNER JOIN Training_venue t2 ON t1.training_id = t2.training_id
WHERE t2.venue_date >= NOW()
ORDER BY t3.venue_date DESC, t2.venue_date ASC
```

Try it!

EDIT: Was using '2010-01-01' instead of `NOW()` as `NOW()` would lose the 2010 dates that you seemed to want included.

Comment: While I agree with AlanBarber above I just thought I was a bit bored and I'd help out. But in future post your attempts so we can help rather than have something done for you.

Comment: @anothershrubery I do agree with you. Usually I try to post my try. Hoverwer I was completly stuck with the double ordering problem, and I've not been able to come up with something close to the "The trainings with the soonest venue is first, the training with the "latest soonest venue" is last" part.

Comment: @anothershrubery I just edited and explained a bit more the point you didn't understood in the initial question.

Comment: I notice you changed `training_id` order in the resultant table! ;)

Comment: @anothershrubery: Hehe, sorry about the 2010 date that bugged you, I should have use 2011 and 2012. I'm trying the query right now...

Comment: @anothershubery Ah ! The key was to use a subquery in a JOIN, that give the possibility to use ON to make a WHERE "inside" the subquery with a parameter that come from the parent query. Brilliant !